# Url redirecting/masking/proxying

Tags: redirects, masking

Sorry about the title, I'm not quite sure what to call what I'm trying to do.

Our university department (distance ed.) has two servers:  a WordPress-only server and a main/everything else server.

**Blog url**:   blog.distance.school.com

**Everything else url**:   distance.school.com

I want to create a WordPress site that lives at: blog.distance.school.com/facultyresources, but when people access it, I want them to see it at:  distance.school.com/facultyresources.

Is this masking? Proxying? I'm not even sure.

**tl;dr:**

— WP will be installed at blog.distance.school.com/facultyresources

— users will access at: distance.school.com/facultyresources

Thanks for any advice you might have!

Comment: Which web server run on both server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're not answering about the web server running on both server, I will give you 2 options:

- on the web server level
- on the client level

**Web Server Level**

If the web server is Apache, you can use the module `mod_proxy` in particular the [proxy pass directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass). Just add this conf on the **distance.school.com** and it will fullfill your request:

```
<Location /facultyresources/>
    ProxyPass http://blog.distance.school.com/facultyresources/
</Location>
```

**The *client* level**

Use a frameset & frame to perform a mask. But user will still be able to access the other url, the one with `blog.` inside. The `index.html` at distance.school.com/facultyresources :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/frameset.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title>Blog</title>
</head>

<frameset cols="*">
  <frame src="http://blog.distance.school.com/facultyresources/" scrolling="no" resize="no" marginwidth="0">
</frameset>

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry j0k! I was refreshing my profile page, but it didn't tell me I had a new comment. Thanks v. much for your answer. I'm interested in server-side redirection. It looks like your suggestion with mod_proxy should do the trick. I'll report back. Thanks for the help.